# 'this' reference undefined

Tags: jquery

onchange of the `select` I'm running the `get_cities_by_countyID()` function. In the function I wrote:

```
function get_cities_by_countyID(countryID) {
  var element = $(this);     
  alert (element.attr("class"));

  // other logic...

  element.closest('form').find('.cityField').html(html);
}
```

However the `alert()` prints `undefined`. How can I fix this?

```
<form>  
  <div class="col-md-5">
    <label>country</label>
    <select class="selectpicker" name="attraction[countryCode]" data-live-search="true" onchange="get_cities_by_countyID(this.value)">
      <option value=""></option>
    </select>
  </div>
  <div class="col-md-5">
    <label>city</label>
    <select class="selectpicker cityField" name="attraction[cityID]" data-live-search="true">
      <option value=""></option>
    </select>   
  </div>
</form>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The issue is because when you assign event handler using the `on*` attributes the function is not called within the scope of the element which raised the event; it's called globally, hence `this` is the window. This is why you receive `undefined`.

To fix this, pass the `this` reference in the event attribute to the function, then retrieve the needed values from there:

```js
function get_cities_by_countyID(el) {
  var $el = $(el);
  var countryId = $el.val();
  console.log($el.prop("class"));
  //element.closest('form').find('.cityField').html(html);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form>
  <div class="col-md-5">
    <label>country</label>
    <select class="selectpicker" name="attraction[countryCode]" data-live-search="true" onchange="get_cities_by_countyID(this)">
      <option value="A">A</option>
      <option value="B">B</option>
      <option value="C">C</option>
    </select>
  </div>
  <div class="col-md-5">
    <label>city</label>
    <select class="selectpicker cityField" name="attraction[cityID]" data-live-search="true">
      <option value="A">A</option>
      <option value="B">B</option>
      <option value="C">C</option>
    </select>
  </div>
</form>
```

However you should note that using the `on*` event attributes is very outdated and should be avoided where possible. Unobtrusive event handlers are much better practice. They also allow you to use the `this` keyword within the handler as a reference to the element which raised the event. As you're using jQuery already you can implement them like this:

```js
$(function() {
  $('#country').on('change', function() {
    var $el = $(this);
    var countryId = $el.val();
    console.log($el.prop("class"));
    //element.closest('form').find('.cityField').html(html);
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form>
  <div class="col-md-5">
    <label>country</label>
    <select class="selectpicker" name="attraction[countryCode]" data-live-search="true" id="country">
      <option value="A">A</option>
      <option value="B">B</option>
      <option value="C">C</option>
    </select>
  </div>
  <div class="col-md-5">
    <label>city</label>
    <select class="selectpicker cityField" name="attraction[cityID]" data-live-search="true">
      <option value="A">A</option>
      <option value="B">B</option>
      <option value="C">C</option>
    </select>
  </div>
</form>
```

Comment: thanks. can i pass THIS to function when i'm using function in my html code? `onchange="get_cities_by_countyID(this.value)"`

Comment: Yes, the first example in the answer shows you how to do that (the one in the hidden snippet). Note that the second example is by far the better way to do this though.

Comment: No problem, glad to help